# Transpose this matrix(python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, transpose

I am trying to find a way to transpose a matrix, for example for:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

it would change the matrix to:

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

So far, I tried several things but it never worked. I tried:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix): # this one doesn't change the matrix at all
    zip(*matrix)
    return matrix
```

or

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
   map(list, zip(*matrix))
   return matrix
```

or

```
 def transpose_matrix(matrix): # this one returns an empty list []
    print(list(zip(*matrix)))
```

I want to code it without using external library such as `numpy`.

After that, it returns the result to this menu and use the transposed matrix for upcoming option (not shown):

```
def menu(matrix):
    print('choose option')
    loop = True
    while loop:
        print('''
        1-display matrix
        7-transpose it
        8-other option
        0-back
        ''')
        choi = input('cchoice:')
        if choi =='1':
            print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))

        elif choix == '7':
            matrix = transpose_matrix(matrix)

        else:
            print('invalid choice')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually *assigning* the result of your manipulations, and therefore return the original `matrix` unchanged. For example:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    zip(*matrix) # ignore result of computation
    return matrix # return argument unchanged
```

Instead, try:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    matrix = list(map(list, zip(*matrix))) # assign result 
    return matrix # return transposed matrix
```

or simply:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    return list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))
```

Bear in mind that you will need to assign the return from the function in the calling function, too:

```
matrix = transpose_matrix(matrix)
```

**In-place modification**

Alternatively, you could transpose in-place and implicitly `return None`:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    matrix[:] = list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))
```

This way you don't have to assign back to `matrix` when you call the function.

**Examples**

Examples of the functions in action:

```
>>> def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    return list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))

>>> transpose_matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
>>> def in_place_transpose(matrix):
    matrix[:] = list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))


>>> m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> in_place_transpose(m)
>>> m
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

**`zip` behaviour**

It is important to note that `zip` will truncate its output to the shortest argument iterable, e.g.:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> c = [7, 8]
>>> d = [9]
>>> e = []
>>> for l in (b, c, d, e):
    print(list(zip(a, l)))


[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 7), (2, 8)]
[(1, 9)]
[]
```

Therefore if any of the rows of your `matrix` are empty lists, your output will be an empty list. You can use [`zip_longest` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to insert dummy `fillvalue`s (`None` by default) instead:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
>>> m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], []]
>>> list(zip_longest(*m, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 4, 0), (2, 5, 0), (3, 6, 0)]
```

You could implement this as:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    return list(map(list, zip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue=0)))
```

with `from itertools import zip_longest` at the top of your script.

Comment: I tried all the options,and each time the matrix remain the same

Comment: @Program_coder I have added more - you need to assign the result of the function or modify the `matrix` in-place

Comment: I tried all and nothing works! I dont get it; either it returns an empty list,or doesnt change the matrix at all; im using print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))to display the matrix in my menu module and it display the same matrix after passing in the transposing module

Comment: @Program_coder are you certain that you are are assigning the result of the computation back to the name `matrix`, or modifying it in-place? This code works perfectly for me. You could edit your question to show precisely what code you have now, what inputs it takes and what outputs you get - you can even paste directly from the interpreter, as I have just done.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe I edited my question for the complete code

Comment: @Program_coder yes, and you haven't assigned the result of `transpose_matrix` to anything. Make it `matrix = transpose_matrix(matrix)`, or use the in-place version of the function. It already tells you this in my answer.

Comment: Sorry,im new in programming.I edited my question,is it what you mean? Under option 7.I tried it,and when I select option 1 to print the matrix, it print [] ,while the matrix before was [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[]]

Comment: @Program_coder ah, finally I see the problem; your example matrices aren't quite representative. I have edited my answer accordingly. Also, note that `'choix' != 'choi'`.

Comment: it says zip_longest global name not defined(error) when I write list(zip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue=0))

Comment: @Program_coder it's part of `itertools`; you will need to `from itertools import zip_longest`

Comment: from itertools import zip_longest 
   list(zip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue=0))
   return matrix   Then when I choose option 1 from my menu above,it display the same matrix

Comment: @Program_coder that code is difficult to read in the comments. However, it looks like you **still aren't actually assigning the result of the computation back to `matrix`**. I give up: put the `import` at the top of your script, and copy and paste the function I just added to the end of my question.

Comment: It finally worked.Finally.Yes! My last question would be,would it be possible to display nothing instead of the 0 value? when I display the list.Thanks a lot for all the support.

Comment: @Program_coder you could use `fillvalue=""` instead, but might get into trouble if later code expects all values to be numbers. Is `0` a valid value for the matrix? You could use the default `fillvalue=None` then `print("\n".join(" ".join(str(i) if i is not None else "" for i in row) for row in matrix))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the solutions you tried:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    zip(*matrix)
    return matrix
```

The result from `zip(…)` is thrown away, and you return the original matrix instead. Write `return zip(*matrix)`.

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
   map(list, zip(*matrix))
   return matrix
```

Same as above, the result from `map(…)` is thrown away. Write `return map(list, zip(*matrix))` instead.

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
    print(list(zip(*m)))
```

The argument is named `matrix`, but you are working on `m`. So either rename the parameter `m`, or change the zipped value to `*matrix`.

---

Examples:

```
>>> m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> list(zip(*m))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>> list(map(list, zip(*m)))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: print(list(zip(*matrix))) print an empty list [],I just tried it

Comment: map(list, zip(*matrix))
   return matrix             leave the matrix same as it was before